# why column order datatable can not be executed

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

when i want order column similarity from Levenshtein calculation result but i get error in ajax_list response

Type: mysqli_sql_exception

Message: Unknown column 'similarity' in 'order clause'

i have code in controller codeigniter3 like this

```
public function ajax_list()
    {           
        $list = $this->article->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        $searchinput=$_POST['search']['value'];
        foreach ($list as $article) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $no;
            $row[] = $article->title;

            $text1   = $row[2];
            $text2  = $searchinput;
            $similarity = levenshtein($text1, $text2) / max(strlen($text1), strlen($text2));
            $result_similarity=(1 - $similarity) * 100;  

            $row[] = $result_similarity;
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->article->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->article->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

and i have code in models like this

```
    var $table = 'article';
    var $column_order = array(null,'title','result_similarity'); //set column field database for datatable orderable
    var $column_search = array('title'); //set column field database for datatable searchable 

    var $order = array('title' => 'asc'); // default order
```

Comment: Is this enough detail to reproduce the problem? If not, see the insturctions on how to create a [mre] for guidance.

Comment: Where is the mysqli code?